# Magento 1.9 Add Backorder status of a product to the product grid in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, product, grid, backend, stock

I'd like to add the status of the back-order in the main manage product grid as an column so I can see it in 1 instance.

the status is visible when you click on a product and go to inventory and you see 'back-order', I'd like that field to be in product grid.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.